# Specific 'boot file' definition

Tags: file, definition, boot

I have been given a general explanation of how a computer boots up.
However a very loose definition to the term 'boot file' was given.

Could someone explain 'boot file' to me in a very simple but concise manner?

I have read about the POST, the clearing of registers, BIOS in the CMOS, etc.
What I understand is that the boot file is different to the boot program.
the boot program gets the system ready to accept an OS while the boot file contains some of the parameters by which the system will operate. 
The boot program is stored on ROM and the boot file isnt?

cheers,
jazz

Comment: Please post some summary of what you've read so far, so we know what aspect of boot loading confuses you.

Comment: Which operating system?  Is this the Windows XP Boot.INI file?  AFAIK, only Winows XP has a "boot file".  I don't think that "boot file" as you're using it is a generic concept.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what they meant by "boot file".

First of all, there's the code in the first sector of the partition that locates the OS kernel, copies it into memory, and gets it running.

Then there's the file on disk that actually has the kernel code, including the stuff that controls the boot process once the boot sector stub has loaded it into memory.

Which one did you want to know about?